Journal name abbreviations
When MathSciNet and Zentralblatt disagree on a journal name abbreviation, is there any way to get them to agree on a common abbreviation?
For example, one of the big journals in algebra in Communications in Algebra.  I've always used "Comm. Alg." for the abbreviation, and MathSciNet also uses that shortening.  Recently, I've also been seeing "Commun. Algebra", which is what Zentralblatt is currently using.

I think that there's a ISO (International Organization for Standardization) norm on abbreviations, but I do not really know its identifier.

Note that sometimes the abbreviation changes over time, e.g., older articles may have a different abbreviation on MathSciNet than newer ones. And also this list is pretty exhaustive/authoritative: https://images.webofknowledge.com/images/help/WOS/A_abrvjt.html

@SamHopkins I recently checked MathSciNet, but actually got it wrong in my post above.  Their current abbreviation is "Comm. Algebra", not "Comm. Alg."  Also, all volumes have been updated to that abbreviation.

@DanieleTampieri I found the ISO 4 link in the upper right corner of the Communications in Algebra wiki page.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_in_Algebra

It appears that Zentralblatt is following the ISO 4 standard, but MathSciNet is not.  Is this the sort of thing that MathSciNet would like to be informed about?

Would you provide links to both?

By the way the MSN abbreviations for Annales Sci. ENS and Publ. IHES are terrible.

I am not sure if AMS is not aware of ISO 4: maybe there are reasons that prevent them from its adoption. I think it could be interesting to ask them about this. I also recall that a senior editor of the AMS Editorial boar is a very active TeXStackexchange member.

I am flabbergasted to learn that there is an ISO standard for abbreviating journal titles. (On the other hand, there is an ISO standard for brewing tea, so maybe I shouldn't be so surprised.) But given that ISO standards are only available at outrageously high prices (it's almost like they don't want anyone to access or use them), and I doubt many math departments will have a subscription to them, I'm not sure this really does us much good.

When my paper will be published electronically only, I write the journal name out in full.  Some publishers (like AMS) may abbreviate the journals themselves, but at least the full name is in the preprint.

I guess you'd need to contact the editors of MR and/or zbMath to get them to change the abbreviation. Both have editorial boards made up of reasonable people.
As mentioned in the comments, as surprising as some may find it, there actually is an ISO standard for abbreviating journal names in bibliographical references. The list is maintained by the ISSN International Center and it is available at: https://www.issn.org/services/online-services/access-to-the-ltwa/ Given that choosing an abbreviation is mostly arbitrary, I think it's best to side with the one that is standard among all disciplines, in case the two standard math databases disagree.
The ISO list does recommend abbreviating "Communications" as "Commun.", not "Comm." The reason it's not abbreviated as "Comm." is rather simple: what if tomorrow, I start a journal called "Commentary of Algebra"? The ISSN center is a serious international organization, they've thought about this and came up with a list that minimizes ambiguities; with some words given special consideration, such as "Journal" being abbreviated as just "J." or "Quarterly" as just "Q." Best take advantage of their work...

If you want to make absolutely sure that there's no ambiguity, it's best to stick the journal's ISSN and/or the article's DOI in there.

Mathematical Reviews generally does follow ISO standards on abbreviations for journals.  However, some journals existed in our coverage before the ISO standards were adopted.  We did not go back to change the abbreviations that predate the standard.  That decision was based on trying not to complicate the record of the journal.  Some of our in-house librarians and catalogers are looking into a way to update old abbreviations for current journals that would avoid making a new record or otherwise complicating our representation of the journal.
